# How to design a browser extension/add-on compatible with multiple browsers

Tags: cross-browser, browser, toolbar

I want to develop an browser extension/add-on which keeps track of the url value in the address bar. The add-on could either be downloaded to local file system or it could be integrated within the browser.

Also, i'm curious to know how browser extensions like [Toolyo](http://www.toolyo.com) are programmed. (It's a demo link of the Toolyo tool. Sorry, I didn't find a better example than this whic is much similar to my requirement). Can someone please throw light on the languages/methods used to develop extensions that can work in multiple browsers.

Sorry for a generic (and vague, as well) question. I would really appreciate any answers/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The extension APIs for browsers with add-on functionality (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) are all very different and much of the browser-chrome-privileged code must be rewritten for the different browsers. User scripts, are a good alternative add-on architecture, but they only have the privilege level of an in-page script (except for GreaseMonkey in Firefox).

Comment: Thanks for an instant response :) Well, in that case, should I need to develop extensions for every individual browsers?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am not aware of a solution that allows the same code to be used for multiple browser add-on APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Greasemonkey is inbuild in Chrome 
And also had support for Flock, Safari and Opera
And its also coming for IE soon.
So writing Greasemonkey script is also good rather then writing code per browser vendor.